# Unbalaced Brackets!? Custom Name + Welcome Message

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm running a vanilla factions server, and I'm running a command through the console because I need to use the § symbol for color-coding.

I tried running this command, but I couldn't figure out how to fix the problem.
Here is the error I'm getting:

```
data tag parsing failed: Unbalanced brackets: {display:{Name:"§3§kO§r§5§lSuperman§3§kO"}, {BlockEntityTag:{Command:"execute @a[score_quit_min=1] ~ ~ ~ say §5§lEnjoy §4§lyou're §6§lstay, §2§lplayer!"}}
```

I'm trying to make a welcome message to the players when they join.

Answer (score 1):

Unbalanced bracket mistakes can become easier to see if you format it like this:

```
{
    display:
    {
        Name:"§3§kO§r§5§lSuperman§3§kO"
    }, 
    {
    BlockEntityTag:
    {
        Command:"execute @a[score_quit_min=1] ~ ~ ~ say §5§lEnjoy §4§lyou're §6§lstay, §2§lplayer!"
    }
}
```

Just before `BlockEntityTag` (which should be in the top tag), you have a stray `{`. The fixed data should be:

```
{display:{Name:"§3§kO§r§5§lSuperman§3§kO"}, BlockEntityTag:{Command:"execute @a[score_quit_min=1] ~ ~ ~ say §5§lEnjoy §4§lyou're §6§lstay, §2§lplayer!"}}
```